# How do you show that the Unruh Temperature between two inertial observers is zero?

Tags: temperature, qft-in-curved-spacetime, unruh-effect

As part of my undergraduate thesis, I'm trying to show that using massless scalar field, the Unruh effect between two inertial observers is zero. I'm using this book: "Introduction to Quantum Fields in Classical Backgrounds" by Sergei Winitzki and Viatcheslav Mukhanov.

I have obtained the transformations between the two null-coordinates and followed the exact same working as in the Rindler case to obtain Bogolyubov coefficients in terms of these coordinate transformations. I am, however, stuck because the final particle density in the vacuum of one frame as observed by the other frame depends on their relative velocity. This is incorrect, in my opinion because the two observers should agree on the definition of the quantum vacuum.

The coordinate transformation between the null coordinates is ($w$ is velocity)
$$
\begin{align}
\bar{u} &= \sqrt{\frac{1-w}{1+w}} u, \\
\bar{v} &= \sqrt{\frac{1+w}{1-w}} v, \\
\textrm{d}\bar{u} &= \sqrt{\frac{1-w}{1+w}} \textrm{d}u, \\
\textrm{d}\bar{v} &= \sqrt{\frac{1+w}{1-w}} \textrm{d}v.
\end{align}
$$

The Bogolyubov transformation is (using dispersion relation $w = |k|$)
$$\hat{b}^{-}_{\Omega} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \textrm{d}\omega \ \left[\sqrt{\frac{\Omega}{\omega}} F(\omega, \Omega)\hat{a}^{-}_{\omega} + \sqrt{\frac{\Omega}{\omega}} F(-\omega, \Omega)\hat{a}^{+}_{\omega}\right],$$
where
$$F(\omega, \Omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\textrm{d}u}{2\pi} e^{i \Omega u - i \omega \bar{u}} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\textrm{d}u}{2\pi} e^{i \Omega u - i \omega \sqrt{\frac{1-w}{1+w}}u}.$$

The particle number density is

> $$\left\langle \hat{N}_{\Omega} \right\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \textrm{d}\omega \ \beta_{-\omega, -\Omega} \beta_{\omega, \Omega}.$$
> Using our definition of $\beta_{\omega,\Omega},$
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \beta_{-\omega, -\Omega} \beta_{\omega, \Omega} &= \frac{\Omega}{\omega}F(\omega, - \Omega)F(-\omega, \Omega), \\
> &= \frac{\Omega}{\omega} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\textrm{d}u}{2\pi} e^{- i \Omega u - i \omega \sqrt{\frac{1-w}{1+w}}u} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\textrm{d}u'}{2\pi} e^{i \Omega u' + i \omega \sqrt{\frac{1-w}{1+w}}u'}, \\
> &= \frac{\Omega}{\omega} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\textrm{d}u}{2\pi} e^{- i\left(\Omega + \omega \sqrt{\frac{1-w}{1+w}}\right)u} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\textrm{d}u'}{2\pi} e^{i\left(\Omega + \omega \sqrt{\frac{1-w}{1+w}}\right)u'}, \\
> &= \frac{\Omega}{\omega} \frac{1}{2\pi} (2\pi) \delta\left(\Omega + \omega \sqrt{\frac{1-w}{1+w}}\right) \frac{1}{2\pi} (2\pi) \delta\left(\Omega + \omega \sqrt{\frac{1-w}{1+w}}\right), \\
> &= \frac{\Omega}{\omega} \delta\left(\Omega + \omega \sqrt{\frac{1-w}{1+w}}\right) \delta\left(\Omega + \omega \sqrt{\frac{1-w}{1+w}}\right), \\ 
> &= \frac{- \omega \sqrt{\frac{1-w}{1+w}}}{\omega}, \\
> &= - \sqrt{\frac{1-w}{1+w}}. 
> \end{align}
> $$

$\beta_{\omega,\Omega}$ is defined in the books to be
$\beta_{\omega,\Omega} = \sqrt{\frac{\Omega}{\omega}} F(-\omega, \Omega); \quad \omega > 0, \ \Omega > 0.$

I just hope it isn't a simple mathematical error and more to do with the interpretation of the number density obtained.

Comment: For those of us who don't have access to the book, what is $\Omega$? By the way, you can write equations using mathjax instead of posting images of equations. For information about how to do this, see [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020).

Comment: Omega is the momentum of the field mode in the other frame. The book does this for the Rindler coordinates. I have followed the same calculation, except that I have used the above mentioned coordinate transformation.

Comment: Your intuition is correct. All inertial observers agree about which state is the vacuum state. I don't have access to the book that you're using, so I can't pinpoint exactly where the mistake enters, but the first equation that relates $b$ to $a$ and $a^\dagger$ already looks suspicious. If you start in an inertial frame, then a Lorentz boost to another inertial frame cannot generate a Bogoliubov transform: the new annihilation operators are linear combinations of the old annihilation operators alone, without involving the creation operators at all. As an easy check, maybe try setting $w=0$.

Comment: Thank you. And I agree with you. A Bogolyubov transformation after a lorentz boost should not mix the operators. However, what I'm trying to do is to show that if I follow the exact same working,  and just use the above coordinate transformation, I should get a zero Unruh temperature. All the working is the same as in the Rindler case, till I substitute the coordinate transformation into $F(\omega,\Omega)$